# CNN is not able to classify images

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

My dataset consists of visualized binaries. Those binaries are either part of `malware family 1` or `malware family 2`. Those grayscale images have very specific features. Some examples (upper family 1, lower family 2):

[image: malware family 1] [image: malware family 1] [image: malware family 1]

[image: malware family 2] [image: malware family 2] [image: malware family 2]

There are 2474 samples of `malware family 1` and 2930 samples of `malware family 2`.
As we can see, the similarities between samples of the same family are very strong. A CNN should not have too much problems classifying them.

Nonetheless, the CNN that I used only achieves around 50% accuracy (and 0.25 loss). In addition to that, I also implemented the `InceptionV3` model. But that model also achieves only 50% accuracy (and 0.50 loss). What could be the error here?

Load images:

```
idx = 0
for elem in os.listdir(directory):
    img = cv2.imread(full_path,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    if idx in train_index:
        dataset4_x_train.append(img)
        dataset4_y_train.append(0)
    else:
        dataset4_x_test.append(img)
        dataset4_y_test.append(0)
dataset4_x_train = np.array(dataset4_x_train)
dataset4_x_test = np.array(dataset4_x_test)

dataset4_x_train = dataset4_x_train.reshape(-1, 192, 192, 1)
dataset4_x_test = dataset4_x_test.reshape(-1, 192, 192, 1)
```

Custom CNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 5, activation="relu", input_shape=(192,192,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(80, 4, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(opt, loss="mse",metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset4_x_train, dataset4_y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=50)   

model.evaluate(dataset4_x_test, dataset4_y_test)
```

InceptionV3:

```
incept_v3 = tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.InceptionV3(input_shape=(192,192,1), include_top=False, weights=None)
incept_v3.summary()

last_output = incept_v3.get_layer("mixed10").output
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(last_output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(incept_v3.input, x)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(opt, loss="mse",metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset4_x_train, dataset4_y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=50)   

model.evaluate(dataset4_x_test, dataset4_y_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Model is under-fitting the dataset, this is why you have a low accuracy.
Fortunately, increasing the model size fixes the problem.
Again, increasing the model size makes it more vulnerable to overfitting. To fix that issue, I would suggest to use dropout layers as shown below.
This is a binary classification problem, for which `binary_crossentropy` loss function will work better, and a low learning to converge to a better accuracy.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu",padding='same', input_shape=(192,192,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(92, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(92, 3, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0008)
model.compile(opt, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset4_x_train, dataset4_y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=50)   

model.evaluate(dataset4_x_test, dataset4_y_test)
```

Comment: This is also a very good implementation. The first few tests are giving me an even higher accuracy than the implementation in the other answer(~99.5%). But I still have to use this method on different datasets to be absolutely sure.

Comment: note that too many epochs may lead to overfitting, for that I would suggest to increase the dropout values from 0.2 to 0.35

Answer (score 1):

MSE is normally used for regression problems, and it sounds like your task is moreso classification, so you should use a different loss function. For example, you can use  `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`. This is most likely the main cause for the low accuracy.

In addition, CNN's normally have more than one hidden linear layer, for example, the following. This would normally have a relatively small performance impact compared to the above.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 5, activation="relu", input_shape=(192,192,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(80, 4, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: I changed the loss function to `BinaryCrossentropy` and converted the labels into the right format with `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(dataset4_y_train/test, num_classes=2)` but I still get an accuracy of ~50% and a loss of 0.7.

Comment: As mentioned by Stanley, increasing the number of `Dense` layers may help

Comment: @DJ001 I have done this, too. But the accuracy is still the same. It's all very weird.

Comment: Using this method in combination with normalizing the 8bit values(0-255) into floats between 0 and 1, I was able to achieve results up to 99% accuracy.  Every now and then I still get a 54% accuracy, but the overall accuracy increased strongly by this.

Comment: Great to hear! My apologies I did not catch the rescale to [0, 1].

Comment: ah yes, rescaling is really a must